# Trying to remove hr separator in the middle of the page, but can't seem to find it anywhere?

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to find it anywhere, and I didn't use the hr tag in any of my html files.

Tried specifying in css `hr { display: none; }` not working either, what the hell is going on?

This isn't a matter of looking hard enough, trust me i've stared at the code for HOURS.

EDIT: thanks everyone >.> lol

Comment: share the code or a link to it?

Comment: It may be a border (border-bottom or bottom-top). Want to post your code?

Comment: Yeah, impossible to answer without some code.

Comment: a link to your site please..and where tell us where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Firebug, I found the culprit. And sure enough as Grillz comments, it's a border, not a horizontal rule:

```
#main {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E7E9;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @user595898: Nothing to be embarrassed about anyway :) Remember to mark the answer accepted using the checkmark (wait a few minutes).

Answer (score 0):

div#main has a border-bottom tag on it on line 273 of the style.css file. try removing that?

Comment: Yeah, i've removed it thanks.^_^